# Comparing two spreadsheets and add data from one if it meets both email address are correct

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel-2011

I want to compare two spreadsheets against using email address and if the email address matches then take information from a cell and add it the the 2nd sheet.

Example Sheet columns:

- ID
- First name
- Last name
- Email address
- City
- State

Sheet 2:

- Account ID
- First Name
- Last name
- City
- State

I want to add Account ID to Sheet one where the emails match

Comment: Sounds like you just need a `VLOOKUP`. Do the spreadsheets need to be separate files, or can you combine both spreadsheets into a single workbook?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare cells in two different spreadsheets and extract data from one an place it in the other if match found](http://superuser.com/questions/467941/compare-cells-in-two-different-spreadsheets-and-extract-data-from-one-an-place-i)

Comment: Sheet 2 doesn't seem to contain email address...